# assigning subclass intance to superclass instance

Tags: objective-c, ios

It might sound very abstract.
Let's say we have the following instances:

```
Shape *aShape
Rectangle *aRect // Rectangle is a subclass or Shape

aRect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
// and some other code to set properties of aRect

aShape = aRect
```

from Obj-C point of view, the last line of assignment is allowed and is valid.
However, in Shape class, not all properties of Rectanlge are defined -- after all, Rectangle is a subclass of Shape.

Doesn't this assignment invalidate some of the aRect's properties and values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not invalidate any of `aRect`'s properties or values. An example from real life - just because you treat someone as a human, does not make them any less man or a woman; you just don't preoccupy yourself with their sex. In the same line of thought, just because you are treating it as a `Shape` in no way does not make it any less `Rectangle`, your code just deal with the "shapeness" aspect of it, ignoring any "rectangularness" whatsoever.

Of course, it is possible that the `Shape` class defines some methods that may change internal state of the `Rectangle` instance into inconsistent state. But that would be a problem even if you call that same method through sending a message to `aRect`. And if the `Rectangle` class overrides such a method to ensure its state is consistent, sending that message through `aShape` would still invoke the correct behavior defined by `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 2):

This is just [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) and does not invalidate any properties they are just no longer "accessible". Of course through means of reflection, or in Objective-C messaging you can still access those values but with a warning unless you cast `aShape` as a `Rectangle`.

```
//This will work if it is a rectangle but will generate a warning
[aShape someRectangleMethod];

//This will work without a warning
[(Rectangle*)aShape someRectangleMethod];
```